# Why 1A matches "[a-zA-Z]+" Regex in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have the folowing code in Java

```
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("1A");
    boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
    if(matchFound) {
      System.out.println("Match found");
    } else {
      System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
```

The result of that says that **1A** match the regex **"[a-zA-Z]+"**.

I only need to **accept words starting with a letter.**

I did the same in question.

Comment: Use _[Matcher#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches())_ instead of _[Matcher#find](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find())_, and at that rate just use _[String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String))_.

Comment: The Matcher class has many methods.  If you had printed out `matcher.start()`, your issue would have been clear.  And reading the documentation of Matcher also would have helped you.

Answer (score 2):

`matcher.find()` finds matches *within* the input; in your case it matches `A`.

You want:

```
"1A".matches("[a-zA-Z].*")
```

[String#matches()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) must match the *entire* String to return `true` (so no need for `^` at the start), and the regex requires that the first character be a letter (the remaining characters, if any, can be anything).

Comment: This would match inputs consisting _only_ of letters, not just starting with letters.

Answer (score -1):

The given RegEx **[a-zA-Z]+** matches a character irrespective of its position in the string. Here 1A is also a match.

If you want to match words starting with a letter use "^" at the beginning of the regex. "**^**" is identify starting of the string.

and to match zero or more letters you can use [a-zA-Z]*, your final regEx looks like this.

exp - **"^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*"**

Comment: I'd like to note that you're correct, except for the addition of the _[a-zA-Z]*_.  Since they're looking to assert that the first character is a letter, just use _^[a-zA-Z]_.